# Specifying the device with lldb on ios

Tags: ios, debugging, lldb

Let's imagine that I have 2 iPhones (or iPads) connected to my Mac and I have to automate a test calling the lldb and loading an app from the COMMAND LINE, not XCODE; so how can I specify which device it should use? Maybe some kind of extra param when calling `platform select remote-ios`?

Answer (score 1):

lldb does not know how to load apps onto an iOS device, or to start up connections to the debug agent on an iOS device.  That bit is done by Xcode, and then the connections are handed off to lldb.  Xcode has a fair bit of support for automating test cases for iOS debugging.  That's the only supported way to do this at present.